# The set of strings over {a, b} that contain the substring a and the substring b

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm attempting this question and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here's what I got.

(a+b)* a (a+b)* b

would this be the regular expression for a set of strings over {a,b} that contain the substring a and substring b?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't include the string ba.

Comment: would ((a+b)* a (a+b)* b )+ ((a+b)* b (a+b)* a) fix that problem..? slightly confused @NicholasViggiano

Comment: @rahulchawla Yes, it would fix that problem. Indeed, that regular expression is correct.

Comment: @TheoBendit just wondering why the original expression isnt correct? wouldnt the first (a+b)* include ba when expanded?

Comment: @rahulchawla It's incorrect because there is no substitution for that (a+b)* terms that would turn (a+b)*a(a+b)*b into ba. While you could make sure ba is a substring very easily, (e.g. ba a aa b), you must always have a b following an a, which ba does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the alphabet. Then the set of words containing the letters $a$ and $b$ can be written as $A^*aA^*bA^* + A^*bA^*aA^*$. This works for any alphabet containing $a$ and $b$.

However, the case $A = \{a,b\}$ is more tricky since in this case the regular expression $A^*(ab + ba)A^*$ would also work, since any word containing $a$ and $b$ contains either the factor $ab$ or the factor $ba$. This would not work with $A = \{a,b,c\}$ since $acb$ contains $a$ and $b$.